# Add custom text in Jasper Reports dynamic

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a dynamic form in jasper reports and I need to add a lable to the `+` button, that adds this form. The config is the following:

```
<dynamic id="improvement_notice_defect_table" required="true" label="Выявленные нарушения">
    <upload id="defect_equipment_attachment" label="Фотография нарушения"/>
    <input_area id="defect_description" label="Описание" required="true"/>
    <dynamic id="defect_std" required="true" label="Не соответствует">
        <input id="defect_std_reference_paragraph" required="true" label="Параграфу(-ам)"/>
        <menu id="defect_std_doc_name" required="true" label="Документу(-ам)"/>
    </dynamic>
</dynamic>
```

I try to add the line

```
<label id="improvement_notice_add_label" label="Добавить нарушение" required="true"/>
```

But if I add it before the last closing tag it is above `+` button and has `_1` added after the text, and if I add it after the tag, it is significantly below `+` button.

Also, this is not my code and I am completely new to the Jasper, so my line can be way off.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

I'm not sure now it has to do with Jasper, maybe it's JSF? Full config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form name="name" prefix=":mainForm:report:dynamic:">
<!--always add dynamic to jasper_cfg file-->
    <menu id="serv_contr_out_id" label="Номер договора" required="true"/>
    <menu id="work_order_out_id" label="Номер наряда-заказа" required="true"/>
    <menu id="proj_number" label="Номер проекта" required="true"/>

    <label id="improvement_notice_doc_id" label="Уведомление о несоответствии №"/>
    <label id="improvement_notice_doc_created" label="Дата создания"/>
    <menu id="improvement_notice_recipient" label="Кому" required="true"/>
    <input_area id="improvement_notice_subject" label="Тема" required="true"/>
    <menu id="improvement_notice_defect_equipment_id" required="true" label="Наименование изделия"/>
    <upload id="improvement_notice_defect_equipment_attachment" required="true" label="Фотография изделия"/>

    <date id="improvement_notice_start_date" required="true" label="Дата составления"/>
    <date id="improvement_notice_end_date" required="true" label="Срок выполнения"/>
    <date id="improvement_notice_issue_receive_date" required="true" label="Дата принятия предписание к исполнению"/>
    <date id="improvement_notice_issue_issue_date" required="true" label="Дата выдачи предписания"/>
    <label id="improvement_notice_issue_recipient" label="Представитель завода" required="true"/>
    <menu id="improvement_notice_issue_is_notice_assigned" label="Подписано представителем завода?" required="true"/>

    <label id="improvement_notice_employee_fio" label="Специалист ТН" required="true"/>
    <upload id="improvement_notice_employee_signature" required="true" label="Подпись"/>

    <menu id="improvement_notice_resolution_employee_fio" required="true" label="Специалист ТН, закрывший предписание"/>
    <upload id="improvement_notice_resolution_employee_signature" required="true" label="Подпись специалиста ТН, закрывшего предписание"/>
    <date id="improvement_notice_resolution_resolve_date" required="true" label="Дата закрытия предписания"/>

    <upload id="improvement_notice_scan_document" anyFile="true" label="Сканированный документ"/>

    <dynamic id="improvement_notice_defect_table" required="true" label="Выявленные нарушения">
        <upload id="defect_equipment_attachment" label="Фотография нарушения"/>
        <input_area id="defect_description" label="Описание" required="true"/>
        <dynamic id="defect_std" required="true" label="Не соответствует">
            <input id="defect_std_reference_paragraph" required="true" label="Параграфу(-ам)"/>
            <menu id="defect_std_doc_name" required="true" label="Документу(-ам)"/>
        </dynamic>
    </dynamic>
    <label id="improvement_notice_add_label" label="Добавить нарушение" required="true"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a very special case, as all this is not standard components, but existing code from another coder. Yet, I think the more answers are there on the internet to this stuff -- the better. Anyway, in case somebody will find this somehow useful.

in the end, there was this structure:

1) The XML file was parsed by class `ADynamicForm` and all tags were added to a list of `Clonable` items, which have all the attributes from file (like `id`, `required`, etc)

2) The page has the following line:

```
<ds:DynamicForm id="dynamic" form="#{cc.attrs.newReport}" update="#{cc.attrs.newReport.update}">
```

where `cc.attrs` means the attributes, defined in `<composite:interface>` tag, and `newReport` being the backing bean, extending `ADynamicForm` abstract class

3) `ds` xmln is defined like this: `xmlns:ds="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"`, therefore we need to look at the file `DynamicForm.xhtml` in the folder `web/WEB-INF/resources/components`.

4) In that file there is a loop `<c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.form.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">`, where `cc.attrs.form` is a class `ADynamicForm`, and `items` are list of items from point 1. In that loop there is a switch-like thingy:

```
<c:when test="#{item.type eq 'DYNAMIC'}">
    <ds:Dynamic id="dynamic_#{status.index}"
        updateAction="#{cc.attrs.update}"
        dynamicItem="#{item}"
        onstart="#{cc.attrs.onstart}"
        oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete}"/>
</c:when>
```

therefore, now we need file `web/WEB-INF/resources/components/Dynamic.xhtml`

5) Finally, in this file we have a loop, that generates all the output html code, and after that loop is the code, that generates `+` button:

```
<p:commandButton style="margin-right: 0.15cm;" action="#{cc.attrs.dynamicItem.addLast}"
    update="containerDyna" onstart="#{cc.attrs.onstart}" title="Добавить элемент: #{cc.attrs.dynamicItem.label.toLowerCase()}"
    oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete}" icon="ui-icon-plus" immediate="true"/>
```

And I was able to add the lable I needed like that:

```
<h:panelGroup style="padding: 10px">
    <h:outputLabel value="Добавить #{cc.attrs.dynamicItem.label.toLowerCase()}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Hope somebody found this useful in some way and I didn't just waste my time :)